# Git check for changes based on path

Tags: git, git-diff

So 
basically, i want a simple way to get a list of my repositories that shows their status.

However, the process is a little slow, annoying but not apocalyptic. My script works fine, but I noticed something curious and wondered if anyone might be able to clarify what is going on.

```
status() 
{
    local OIFS="$IFS"
    IFS="|"
    local rootdir=$(pwd)
    local folders=$(find -maxdepth 2 -type d -printf "%P|")

    folders=${folders}
    for folder in $folders 
    {   
        if [[ -n $folder ]]; then
            curdir=$rootdir/$folder
            if [[ -d $curdir/.git ]]; then 
                cd "$curdir"
                #branch=$(git --git-dir="$curdir/.git" symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD 2> /dev/null)
                branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
                #git --git-dir="$curdir/.git" diff-index --quiet HEAD -- 
                git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- 
                case $? in
                    0) printf "\e[1;34m[Clean]\e[0m %s \e[36m(%s)\e[0m\n" "$folder" "$branch";;
                    1) printf "\e[1;31m[Dirty]\e[0m %s \e[36m(%s)\e[0m\n" "$folder" "$branch";;
                esac
            fi;
        fi;         
    }
    cd $rootdir
    IFS="$OIFS"
}
```

As you can see it is quite simple really, giving me a colorized output of each actual repository, the current branch it is one, and a Clean/Dirty indicator for the local status.  (has changes or not).

the funny part is the commented out lines using the "--git-dir" command.
I was thinking that it might be nice to not have to "cd $curdir" for every folder just run the git commands, and I remembered that the --git-dir could be used to force the location of the repository.

For the retrieval of the current branch this is not a problem, but for the diff-index it has some *strange* behavior.

First:  if I run the command without the --quiet option, the return code (0 or 1) is returned correctly.  However, if I use the --quiet it always returns $? as 1.  If I don't use the --git-dir option, the exit code is always accurate 0 or 1, but the --git-dir option and the --quiet option messes the whole thing up.  Why is that?  (just curious really)

As for the other things:

A) is there another way to get the correct return code from diff-index while still hiding the output and using the --git-dir functionality?

B) Any ideas how to speed this function up, either though other means of getting the branch and commit status of the repository, etc?

Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner

Comment: Have you profiled this to see what's slow about it?  If I had to guess, it's having to pull a bunch of uncached data off disk, which is why a `git status` will be really slow in a large repository if you haven't run it in a while.  That, unfortunately, you can't do much about.

Comment: According to the documentation, `git diff-index` "compares the <tree-ish> and the files on the filesystem", so you will need `--work-tree` as well as `--git-dir`. That would be true *regardless of the `--quiet` setting* though, so I'm not sure what you have encountered here.

Comment: The --work-tree worked great, thanks!

Comment: Xiong, how would go about "profiling" a function in git bash?  I mean all I'm really wanting to look up is if there changes, not what those changes are (if that's possible). Thanks.